# Restful Webservices PostforObject an object and a date parameter

Tags: java, rest

I searched for many possibilities, but nothing worked and this is my last try. 
Here I invoke the Requestmapping.

```
private static double exampleMethod(List<Cashflow> cashflowList, Date date) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String url = "http://localhost:9080/example/method";
    Map<String, String> verbar = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    verbar.put("date", date);

    return restTemplate.postForObject(url, cashflowList, Double.class, verbar);
}
```

Here is the method that I want to give the list with objects and the date.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/verbarwertung", params = { "date"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)  
@ResponseBody   
public double verbarwertung(@RequestParam("date") Date datum, @RequestBody List<Cashflow> cashflowList) {

    double cashflow = 0;
    double datumDiff = 0;
    TimeUnit timeunit = TimeUnit.DAYS;
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal2.setTime(datum);
    for (int i = 0; i < cashflowList.size(); i++) {
        cal.setTime(cashflowList.get(i).getDatum());
        if (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == cal2.get(Calendar.MONTH) && cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) == cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
            cashflow = cashflowList.get(i).getCashflow();
            long diffInMillies = cashflowList.get(cashflowList.size() - 1).getDatum().getTime()
                        - cashflowList.get(i).getDatum().getTime();
            double restLaufzeit = timeunit.convert(diffInMillies, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            datumDiff = restLaufzeit / 365;    
        }
    }


    double barwert;

    barwert = cashflowList.get() / Math.pow(1 + zins, datumDiff);

    return barwert;     
}
```

Everything that I try end in this error. Thank you for your help guys. :)

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:621) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:321) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at de.ErmittlungBarwert.verbarwertung(ErmittlungBarwert.java:149) ~[classes/:na]
    at de.ErmittlungBarwert.main(ErmittlungBarwert.java:53) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) ~[com.ibm.websphere.javaee.servlet.3.1_1.0.16.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[com.ibm.websphere.javaee.servlet.3.1_1.0.16.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1290) ~[na:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:778) ~[na:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:475) ~[na:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:148) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.16.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:94) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.16.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.16.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.16.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.16.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.16.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.16.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.16.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.16.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.16.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.16.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.16.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.16.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.16.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.16.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.16.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.16.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.16.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.security.jaspi.JaspiServletFilter.doFilter(JaspiServletFilter.java:57) [com.ibm.ws.security.jaspic.1.1_1.0.16.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.16.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.16.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:1021) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.16.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1143) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.16.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4956) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.16.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer31.osgi.webapp.WebApp31.handleRequest(WebApp31.java:525) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.3.1_1.0.16.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:315) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.16.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1014) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.16.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:280) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.16.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:967) [com.ibm.ws.transport.http_1.0.16.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.wrapHandlerAndExecute(HttpDispatcherLink.java:359) [com.ibm.ws.transport.http_1.0.16.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:318) [com.ibm.ws.transport.http_1.0.16.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:471) [com.ibm.ws.transport.http_1.0.16.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:405) [com.ibm.ws.transport.http_1.0.16.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:285) [com.ibm.ws.transport.http_1.0.16.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:256) [com.ibm.ws.transport.http_1.0.16.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:174) [com.ibm.ws.channelfw_1.0.16.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:83) [com.ibm.ws.channelfw_1.0.16.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504) [com.ibm.ws.channelfw_1.0.16.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574) [com.ibm.ws.channelfw_1.0.16.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:929) [com.ibm.ws.channelfw_1.0.16.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1018) [com.ibm.ws.channelfw_1.0.16.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

Comment: The problem in your code is at the line 149 of the ErmittlungBarwert class. Which is the instruction ?

Comment: That is the `return restTemplate.postForObject(url, cashflowList, Double.class, verbar);`

Comment: Are you sure ? The call in the stack refers to the getForEntity() method.

Comment: Sorry wrong error message, but before I tried it with get and postforEntity and I got the same problem

Comment: Ok I understand. The problem is not visible from your stacktrace. You call a remote service that encounters a problem. You should look at the error log written by this remove service.

Comment: how do I get an other log?

Comment: That is the only error message I get by starting the app on the websphere